# Jenkins + Git plugin = wrong files being retrieved

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a strange issue with Jenkins Pipelines and Git.

The plan is that whenever any code is checked in, Jenkins will trigger the pipeline.

I can see my event being sent from Github and viewing the payload shows the correct commit hases, but when the job is triggered, Jenkins is using a random commit.  I had assumed that the git plugin would work with the Git push and would work out which commit it was to use itself.  However I am now thinking I have missed a crucial piece of config. I've searched around and nothing is hinting at my mistake.  Anyone willing to offer a hand?

Comment: To add some extra info - I can see the payload has the correct commit has, but when the pipeline is triggered it is a totally different hash shown.  I had used the GeneralSCM plugin and thought that would be the issue, so changed to the Git plugin - which has the same issue.  Also - not sure if relevant - but the webhook is using JSON

Comment: can you post your Jenkinsfile

Comment: Not using a jekins file at present - just a pipeline -

`stage('Checkout Code') {
            steps {
                git branch: '**', credentialsId: 'JOE-GIT', url: 'https://github.com/path/repo.git'
            }
}`

this should be called whenever the push from github is recieved

Comment: instead of the wildcard for branch use `env.BRANCH_NAME` if you are using the Multibranch pipeline

Comment: I'm aiming for code to run no matter which branch code is commited on.  Currently using a standard pipeline (not a multibranch)

Comment: To explain the situation.  We have a "devlop" branch and develpers work on feature commits on branches named for stories.  Once the developer has pushed their code to their branch, I'd like to run unit tests automatically (after this point there are different ideas about where to go) -What I have found so far, is that github sends the webhook to jenkins and jenkins is kicking off work,  But sometimes the commit in Jenkins is not matching the commit hash from guthub.